# Redirect the user to another URL using Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a way to redirect the incoming URL to another URL?

EX - when user hits https://www.website1.com, user should be redirected to https://www.website2.com

Answer (score 1):

CloudFoundry itself does *not* provide a way to redirect arbitrary requests prior to requests hitting an application (i.e. at the Gorouter layer).

You have some options though:

1. Perform redirects on your load balancer. If you need to redirect the request as early as possible, doing it on your load balancers would be the earliest possible place. This is good for example if you want to redirect all requests from HTTP to HTTPS. It does assume that your load balancer will allow this, and not all do.
2. You can redirect from an application. So in your example, the application to which you have mapped the route [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com) would be listening and issue the redirect response to send requests to [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com).

   This app could be something as simple as an `nginx.conf` pushed using the [Nginx Buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/index.html), or you could develop a custom application to issue the redirects. The beauty of this is that you can map any number of routes (including wildcards) to the app and a single Nginx server, configured correctly, could issue redirects for all of them. If you are redirecting a lot of separate URLs to one central URL, this works well.

   If you have an existing application on [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com) and cannot replace it with an Nginx app to do the redirects, you could modify your custom application to perform the redirects. You don't have to use Nginx, it is just a convenient and very low overhead way to do redirects.
3. You could use a route service. [Route Services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html) are able to filter requests and so you could use one to intercept requests and issue redirects for certain routes/domains.

   A route service can make some sense if you have complicated routing logic or if you have many applications to which you need to apply the logic. The reason is that a route service requires a custom application to be the route service. So if you have one application and you're trying to redirect requests for that one application to somewhere else, it doesn't make sense to add a second application into the mix just to perform some redirects. Now, if you have 500 applications and they all need some sort of redirect logic, it could make a little more sense to use a route service.